# How to Access attr("id") of parentNode (d3js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm still fighting with d3js.
Simple Question, how can I Access Attributes of a parentNode?

This doesn't work:

```
d3.selectAll(".selectedGraphic").each(function (d, i) {
    console.log(d3.select(this).node().parentNode.attr(0));
});
```

It throws "object doesn't support attr function or method"

Thanks so far :)

Comment: As you wrote, @altocumulus, this the right solution:

    `d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")`

I'm still confused about when DOM and when d3-objects are in use.
I was sure, that "this" is a d3-object and therefore it was logic for me that parentNode is also a d3-object.
Is there a documentation, where I can have a look for better understanding?
The d3js.org documentation didn't help me much yet :(

Comment: `.parentNode` is a native DOM property whereas `.attr()` belongs to the D3 API; you need to wrap the DOM element in a D3 selection to use that method: d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")`. Alternatively, you can directly access the element's `id` property: `this.parentNode.id`.

Comment: From the API docs on [`selection.each`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_each): "with *this* as the current DOM element". It couldn't be much clearer, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, you are Right. I didn't find this section.

Comment: Now I have a line which id I can set like `drawObject.attr("id", newID)`
This Object is a child of a g-element:
`<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" pointer-events="fill"><line class="coldwater graphic" x1="490" y1="270" x2="150" y2="260" /></g>`

I'd like to give this g-element the new id-attribute, instead of the line but if I try this: `d3.select(drawObject.parentNode).attr("id", newID);` nothing happens.
If I then try to read an attribute like `d3.select(drawObject.parentNode).attr("id")`I get this error:
`0: Unable to get property 'getAttribute' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: You are still mixing native DOM and D3 selections ;-) Since `drawObject` seems to be a D3 selection the following should do the trick: `d3.select(drawObject.node().parentNode).attr("id", newID)`.

Comment: Like I said earlier, `drawObject.node().parentNode.id = newId` will work just as well without the overhead of creating a new D3 selection.

Comment: I'm totally confused.
Above you wrote this:  `d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")`<br>
I thought here "this" was a d3-object. So "this" was the DOM and with selct, you made it to a d3-object.
Thank you, for bringing light in my brain.

Comment: That depends on where you are using the statement: **inside** `.each()` and similar methods of a D3 selection `this` refers to a native DOM node; **outside** of those functions `this` refers to something different. My last two comments dealt with a statement outside of those D3 methods. Almost never does `this` refer to a D3 selection, though.

Comment: Yes, I understood.
For getting sure, I logged These both Elements to see the difference.
d3 is Always from type object and DOM could be e.g. SVGLineElement or something like this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.